# Ways to simplify repeatitive codes

Tags: excel, vba

I need to run alot of codes that is similar to this (below). 
May I check if there are ways to simplify my code ? 
what it does: Basically draws data from an excel and update on a table in powerpoint

```
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(2, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("A5").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(3, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("A6").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(4, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("A7").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(5, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("A8").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(6, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("A9").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(7, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("A10").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(8, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("A11").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(9, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("A12").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(10, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("A13").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(11, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("A14").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(12, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("A15").Text
'Update 2nd column
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(2, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("B5").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(3, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("B6").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(4, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("B7").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(5, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("B8").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(6, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("B9").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(7, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("B10").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(8, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("B11").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(9, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("B12").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(10, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("B13").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(11, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("B14").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(12, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("B15").Text
'Update 3rd column
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(2, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("C5").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(3, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("C6").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(4, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("C7").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(5, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("C8").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(6, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("C9").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(7, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("C10").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(8, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("C11").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(9, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("C12").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(10, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("C13").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(11, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("C14").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(12, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("C15").Text
'Update 4th column
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(2, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("D5").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(3, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("D6").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(4, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("D7").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(5, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("D8").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(6, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("D9").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(7, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("D10").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(8, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("D11").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(9, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("D12").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(10, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("D13").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(11, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("D14").Text
ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(12, 4).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range("D15").Text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of(A to D) letters than an array of cell cols (2 to 12)

```
Dim Letters(4) As String
Letters(0) = "A"
Letters(1) = "B";
Letters(2) = "C";
Letters(3) = "D";

Dim Cols(11) As Integer
Cols(0) = 2
Cols(1) = 3
Cols(2) = 4
Cols(3) = 5
Cols(4) = 6
Cols(5) = 7
Cols(6) = 8
Cols(7) = 9
Cols(8) = 10
Cols(9) = 11
Cols(10) = 12

Dim rowIndex = 1
Dim startIndex = 5
```

Then loop through letters

```
For i = 0 to 3
    startIndex = 5
    For j = 0 to 10
    ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(Cols(j), rowIndex).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Range(Letters(i) + "" + startIndex).Text
    startIndex = startIndex + 1
Next
rowIndex = rowIndex +1   
Next
```

Comment: Thanks very much JustLearning. The looping through letter is insightful. I will probably have many use for this technique to keep the code easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is exactly what loops are for. For your example code, the following could replace the entire block:

```
Sub looping()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

For i = 1 To 4
    For j = 2 To 12
        ppPres.Slides("China_A_T10").Shapes("China_A_T10").Table.Cell(i, j).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = xlBook.Worksheets("China_A_T10").Cells(j + 3, i).Text
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

The way this works is by assigning your table cell row and column values to an integer, which changes every run of the loop. The worksheet ranges should be in the same shape so the same integer adjusted by starting position should grab from the correct cell. Then it loops for every column, and for every row and sets all positions.

Please note it might need adjusting to your data, please back it up before running so you don't lose anything.

Also this can be sped up with things like `Application.screenupdating = false` or by reading this all into an array and doing your output in one go.

Comment: Thanks Plutian. This is indeed helpful.

Comment: xlBook.Worksheets(cnaluxux).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Text

Hi Plutian, may I check if you know how should I rewrite the Range.end(xlUp).text portion using your method above? I am not sure how to put them into .Cells(i , j). My idea is to loop from excel columns (eg, B,C,D,E) and take only the last visible data to enter into PPT table.

Comment: That statement should work just fine, just make sure to put the sheet name in quotes. `Worksheets("cnaluxux")`. If you want to only write to the last available column in your table, swap out the `for j = 2 to 12` loop for a j = last row calculation in your table and you're good to go.

Comment: No problem, I'm here to help! If you feel like your issue is resolved feel free to accept my answer, or let me know if there is anything else you're struggling with.